# Display posts with tag that matches current post title

Tags: posts, query-posts, tags

How would I show posts that have a tag who's name matches the title of the current post?
For example if you are on a post called "Hippo" at the bottom of the page I would like posts with the tag "Hippo" to be displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query would look something like this:

```
$title_tagged_posts_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'tag' => strtolower( get_the_title() )
) );

while ( $title_tagged_posts_query->have_posts() ) : $title_tagged_posts_query->the_post();
    //Output whatever you want here.
endwhile;
```

This assumes that the tag slug for "Hippo" is "hippo", which should normally be the case.

Comment: Thanks but I'm having a heard time getting it to output content. Does it work similar to a querypost? for example where you have the comment I put `echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'videoembed',true) ;` and I get nothing output.

Comment: It should work similarly - have you make sure to declare $post as a global? (`global $post`). As an alternative, you could use the `get_the_ID()` function: `get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'videoembed', true );`